# Cox regression to see if distribution of disease predicts survival

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, cox-model

I'm working with clinical data from a few hundred patients. Every patient was measured at 6 different timepoints with regular intervals.

Each patient is assessed on 3 different domains and given a score for each domain ranging from 0 - 11. On this scale 11 is perfect and 0 is the worst score. A very focal distribution of scores is 11,11,0 and an example of a very diffuse distribution is 7,7,7.

The research question is whether the distribution of the scores is related to survival length of the patient. My current approach is the following: I subtract the lowest score from the two other scores and square each. For example: a score of 0,2,11 yields a value of (11-0)2 + (2-0)2 = 125.

Subsequently, I perform a cox regression to look at the correlation with survival.

Furthermore, I want to match the pattern of progression of the patient to a very focal progression of disease, i.e. someone who progresses to 0,11,11 rather than 8,7,7 for a sum of 22. This would allow to incorporate the data of multiple timepoints in the analysis.

Do you think the cox regression is a fitting approach? The problem is that there is a different outcome possible for each sum of the three domains.

Secondly, what analysis would I have to do to relate the degree to which the pattern of progress matches with survival?